# If every uncountable subset of an infinite graph has an infinite clique, must the graph have an uncountable clique?

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-graphs

Let $G$ be an uncountably infinite graph. $G$ has the property that every uncountable set of nodes includes an infinite clique. Must $G$ contain an uncountable clique?

A simple proof would be to try a Ramsey theorem-like approach to the contrapositive and say "no uncountable clique implies uncountable independent set", but this is apparently not true ([Theorem 3.1](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jbaek/infinite-ramsey.pdf)). I'm worried this problem might just be way over my head and I'll waste a lot of time thinking about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same counterexample as to the Ramsey theorem you suggest works for your question.  Let $<^*$ be a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ and consider the graph on $\mathbb{R}$ with an edge between $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ if $<^*$ agrees with the usual ordering $<$ on $\{x,y\}$.  Since there is no uncountable well-ordered subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the usual ordering, there is no uncountable clique.

However, I claim every uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contains an infinite clique.  Indeed, suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.  Replacing $A$ by a subset, we may assume that $A$ has order-type $\omega_1$ with respect to $<^*$.  Let $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:[x,\infty)\cap A\text{ is countable}\}$ and $x=\inf B$.  Since there is a sequence of points of $B$ that approach $x$ from above, $x\in B$, so $B\cap A$ is countable.  This means that replacing $A$ with $A\setminus B$, we may assume that for each $a\in A$, $A\cap[a,\infty)$ is uncountable.

Now we construct an infinite clique in $A$.  Pick any element $a_0\in A$.  Since $A$ has order-type $\omega_1$, all but countably many $b\in A$ satisfy $a_0<^* b$.  Since $A\cap [a_0,\infty)$ is uncountable, this means we can pick $a_1\in A$ such that $a_0<a_1$ and $a_0<^* a_1$.  We can then similarly find $a_2\in A$ such that $a_1<a_2$ and $a_1<^* a_2$.  Continuing this process, we can recursively construct a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ which is strictly increasing with respect to both orders.  This gives an infinite clique in $A$.

Comment: That sounds about right - I was working on a similar construction a couple hours after I posted this question. Do we really need the assumption that $A$ is $\omega_1$? Once we apply the reduction in your second paragraph, say we let $a_0$ be the $<^*$-smallest element of $A$. Now let $a_{n+1}$ be the smallest element of $(a_n, \infty)\cap A$.

Comment: Sure, that would work too.